# Can we change the order of "Period" column after any other column in magento 1 grid

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid, product-grid

can we change the order of the **"Period"** column from **first to second** or any **other position** in the **grid**. Like after **SKU** or **product name** ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Custom Order Grid for Magento 1](https://www.iwdagency.com/extensions/custom-order-grid-m1.html) plugin. It allows you to edit & rearrange columns pretty easily. In this way, you can quicken your workflow significantly.